# Problem with package gmp: \sqrt in label

Tags: metapost, embedding

It is quite weird that the `gmp` package cannot corporate with `\sqrt` in label. The MME on [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/2263475237jtmmvyjrcjfr):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}%nowrite
\usempxclass{amsart}
\usempxpackage{amssymb}

\title{Metapost+gmp}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{mpost}
            draw fullcircle scaled 100pt;
            label(btex $r=10$ etex, origin);
            %to test, un-comment the following line:
            %label(btex $r=\sqrt{100}$ etex, origin);
        \end{mpost}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have test that, the problem not appear in `mpgraphics`. Is it a bug for `gmp`?

### UPDATE:

the error message:

```
l.17  label(btex
                 $r=\protect \let \reserved@d =[\def \begingroup \def ##1,{}...
The two files given above are one of your source files
and an auxiliary file I need to read to find out what your
btex..etex blocks mean. If you don't know why I had trouble,
try running it manually through MPtoTeX, TeX, and DVItoMP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When LaTeX macros are needed in a `label`, use `\btex`, rather than `btex`:

```
\begin{mpost}
  draw fullcircle scaled 100pt;
  label(\btex $r=\sqrt{100}$ etex, origin);
\end{mpost}
```

It is already announced at the bottom of page 1 in the documentation

> This has some consequences; for example, METAPOST labels will usually go inside
>   `\btex ... etex`

See also the example in figure 6 and look for `\btex` in the manual.

[image]

Why is `\btex` necessary? Because one of the aims of `gmp` is to be able passing LaTeX macros to the `mpost` environment mainly in order to use lengths depending on the context. Thus the `.mp` file is written with *full expansion*. A few macros would not suffer from this, but a label using `btex...etex` typically contains things that need to be protected from premature expansion.

Therefore the `\btex...etex` method has been devised; basically it becomes

```
btex \unexpanded{...} etex
```

when it is passed for being written to the `.mp` file, thus the effect is to write the `btex ... etex` construction “literally”.

In a standard `.mp` file `\btex` is completely equivalent to `btex`, because `\` is defined to be `relax`, so copying and pasting to another `.mp` file is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Or if `lualatex` is a suitable option for you, you might like to try the `luamplib` approach.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%-----------
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\everymplib{verbatimtex \leavevmode etex; beginfig(0);}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
% see: `texdoc luamplib` for details...
%----------
\usepackage{amssymb}
\title{Metapost+luamplib}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
        \begin{mplibcode}
            draw fullcircle scaled 100pt;
            label("$r=10$", 20 up);
            label("$r=\sqrt{100}$", origin);
        \end{mplibcode}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

With the `\mplibtextextlabel{enable}` option, you can just use strings instead of the `btex .. etex` mechanism, and no special escapes are needed.

[image]